# Change the view element property based on ViewModel property change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I would like to change the color of my `Label` in the view based on a type in my ViewModel. For ex:

My class in ViewModel has a `bool` property like following:

```
MyViewModel
{
public bool IsBlueColor {get; set;} //Here I will raise the `PropertyChanged`
}
```

How can I wrap a trigger for this value to update `Foreground` property of my label. All I could figure out was changing the property of UI element based on its on property using `DataTrigger`. But not based on viewmodel.

How can I achieve this in xaml?

Right now I am doing this:

```
<Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger   Binding="{Binding Path=IsBlueColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local2:MyViewModel}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=IsBlueColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local2:MyViewModel}}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because RelativeSource bindings bind relative to the control itself, not the control's data context. Your binding is trying to find a parent control of type MyViewModel, which obviously won't work because your view model isn't a control. Nikita's answer is correct, or if your view model is set as your main Window's data context then you can use RelativeSource with a type of Window and a path of DataContext.IsBlueColor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the style triggers to:

```
<Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBlueColor}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
           </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=IsBlueColor}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           </DataTrigger> 
</Style.Triggers>
```

Check implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in ViewModel.

this works in a sample for me.

Sample :

```
class LabelViewModel:INPC
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged=new delegate{};
 bool _isBlueColor;
 public bool IsBlueColor
 {
  get
  {
    return _isBlueColor;
  }
  set
  {
    _isBlueColor=value;
    OnPropertyChange();
  }
}
public OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propname="")
{
  PropertyChanged.Invoke(this,ew PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
}

}
```

Create an instance of LabelViewModel(labelVM) & assign to label1.DataContext=labelVM;

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately it doesn't work. What should be the style wrapper on this? Currently my target type is `Label` so which will not have `IsBlueColor` property.

Comment: The targetType will be Label itself , IsBlueColor should be property of the ViewModel that is provided as the dataContext for the given Label. the trigger represents "When the IsBlueColor property is true in the ViewModel set the foreground property of the label as RoyalBlue".

Comment: Check the updated answer,I have added the sample code.